# Display input label instead of identifier

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app I want to display the label of input instead of the input code. Anyone knows how to do this? Here is an example below, in this example when one select First Variable, "var1" is returned, however I want "First Variable" to be returned.

I could write something reactive (i.e. ifelse input_variable equals var1 then return "First Variable" but if var2 then return "Second Variable" and so on). But there must be a more efficient way right?

Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "input_variable", label = "Variable",
              choices = c("First Variable" = "var1", "Second Variable" = "var2", "Third Variable" = "var3"),
              selected = "var1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    input$input_variable
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding the values twice, create a lookup vector and use that for both the UI and the server logic:

```
values <- c('First variable', 'Second variable', 'Third variable')
vars <- paste0('var', seq_along(values))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "input_variable", label = "Variable",
              choices = setNames(vars, values),
              selected = "var1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    values[match(input$input_variable, vars)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```